# Similarity Measures for Spectral Analysis

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing, fft, similarity

I'm trying to compare the spectral analysis (results of FFT - Fourier transform) on different signals.

Thus, I have a vector with the magnitude of the signal at each spectral point (ie. the results of the power spectrum).

Intuitively, I think that eucledian is the most relevant as I have signals of the same length (as opposed to text documents, for example).

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming question

Comment: Consider also cosine simularity

Answer (score 1):

Try intersection over union ([Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)), it is better suited for comparing distributions. It is quite easy to generalize it to discrete series.